# Separating data by unique column values

Tags: r

Edit to make the problem more clear:  I start with a messy CSV file so I need to identify what is the ID and what is the time variable. Or assign ID and time to the data in the variable columns. This question has now been answered below.
Here is my data:

```
col1<-c("ID", "Date","var1","var2","ID","Date","var1","var2","ID","Date","var1","var2")
col2<-c("1","21-11-2015 14:20", "4.8","3.8", "1","21-11-2015 15:30", "3.5","5.9","2","21-11-2015 14:20","3.0","6.7")
df<-cbind(col1,col2)
```

I tried with `dcast()` with no luck:

```
dcast(ID+Date~var1+var2, data = df, value.var = col1 )
```

I would like the output to be  a true long format like this:

```
ID<-c(1,1,2)
Date<-c("21-11-2015 14:20","21-11-2015 15:30","21-11-2015 14:20")
var1<-c("4.8","3.5","6.7")
var2<-c("3.8","5.9","3.0")
df.clean<-cbind(ID,Date, var1,var2)
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(cbind.data.frame(df, grp = cumsum(df[, "col1"] == "ID")), grp ~ col1, value.var = "col2")`

Comment: Firstly, from your examples your trying to go from long to wide (now in the OP comments). Secondly, the csv is overly long which makes things more difficult but that's just the unfortunate world you're in. Thirdly, df isn't a data.frame or data.table as you have written but rather a matrix.    
A syntax issue is that you don't have any columns named ID or Date. Everything in the dcast formula must be a column name. Check out [this vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) about reshaping with dast and melt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think this is a reshape question, you have values in one column and names in other which can be gathered together and given names using `setNames`

```
with(df, setNames(data.frame(matrix(col2,
          ncol = length(unique(col1)), byrow = TRUE)), unique(col1)))

#  ID             Date var1 var2
#1  1 21-11-2015 14:20  4.8  3.8
#2  1 21-11-2015 15:30  3.5  5.9
#3  2 21-11-2015 14:20  3.0  6.7
```

**data**

```
col1<-c("ID", "Date","var1","var2","ID","Date","var1","var2","ID",
        "Date","var1","var2")
col2<-c("1","21-11-2015 14:20", "4.8","3.8", "1","21-11-2015 15:30", 
         "3.5","5.9","2","21-11-2015 14:20","3.0","6.7")
df<- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a reshape question. Here I supply a simple code on how to do it manually:

**Data**

```
col1<-c("ID", 
        "Date","var1","var2","ID","Date","var1","var2","ID","Date","var1","var2")
col2<-c("1","21-11-2015 14:20", "4.8","3.8", "1","21-11-2015 15:30", 
        "3.5","5.9","2","21-11-2015 14:20","3.0","6.7")
df<-data.frame(col1,col2, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Code**

```
uniquevars<-unique(col1)
Res<-list()
for(i in 1:length(uniquevars)){
  Res[[uniquevars[i]]]<-df[,"col2"][which(df[,"col1"] ==uniquevars[i])]
}

dfRes <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(Res), ncol=length(Res)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(dfRes)<-uniquevars
dfRes
      ID             Date var1 var2
    1  1 21-11-2015 14:20  4.8  3.8
    2  1 21-11-2015 15:30  3.5  5.9
    3  2 21-11-2015 14:20  3.0  6.7
```

I hope this code makes you understand the steps to follow on what you are interested in doing.

Cheers !

Comment: All three solutions work beautifully. I see that I asked the question a bit wrong as it was more of a data tidying problem than a wide-long format problem. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%                                # your original (cbind) object
  data.frame() %>%                    # set as dataframe
  group_by(col1) %>%                  # for each col1 value
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%    # set a row index (useful for reshaping)
  spread(col1, col2) %>%              # reshape
  select(-index)                      # remove index

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Date             ID    var1  var2 
#   <fct>            <fct> <fct> <fct>
# 1 21-11-2015 14:20 1     4.8   3.8  
# 2 21-11-2015 15:30 1     3.5   5.9  
# 3 21-11-2015 14:20 2     3.0   6.7
```